# Psuedo Element two line issue

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using Pseudo element for  underline on my web page title but when the screen size reduces it's not working properly
here is my CSS code and screenshot

```
 .section-title {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .section-title:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom: solid 5px #2874f0;
    top: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Edit the question with a working fiddle. where do you want the line to appear?

Comment: It's simple: don't position it absolutely.

Comment: try `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

.section-title {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .section-title:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    border-bottom: solid 5px #2874f0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways that come to mind:

1. Place `<br>` in one `h*` tag to make multiple lines and add this CSS property:

   ```
   text-decoration:underline;
   ```
2. Use multiple `h*` tags and apply the `border-bottom` as you already have done. Also to control vertical spacing use the following:

   ```
   line-height: 30px;
   padding:0;
   display:table;
   ```

### Demo

---

```css
h1.A {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center
}

h1.B {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding:0;
  display:table;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='A'>Three<br>Line<br>Title</h1>


<h1 class='B'>Three</h1>
<h1 class='B'>Line</h1>
<h1 class='B'>Title</h1>
```